# How to identify infra already matches terraform config

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a pipeline for executing terraform scripts in Azure DevOps, instead of running predefined terraform tasks(which wasn't included in our organization yet) I am planning to run the scripts through Azure CLI. My question is, is there a way we can identify in the terraform plan if "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.", so that I dont have to run the terraform apply.

I know that terraform apply won't harm if the Configuration matches. I am planning to skip that command, Is there a way to check the plan output and make the decision out of it through Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You should use `-detailed-exitcode`. Here you have an example in bash:

```sh
    terraform init
    terraform plan -out=plan.out -detailed-exitcode

    status=$?
    echo "The terraform command exit status : ${status}"

    #run apply only on changed detected
    if [ $status -eq 2 ]; then
        echo 'Applying terraform changes'
        terraform apply -auto-approve plan.out
    elif [ $status -eq 1 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
```

Here you have [link to documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#other-options)

> Returns a detailed exit code when the command exits. When provided, this argument changes the exit codes and their meanings to provide more granular information about what the resulting plan contains:
>
> - 0 = Succeeded with empty diff (no changes)
> - 1 = Error
> - 2 = Succeeded with non-empty diff (changes present)